# Ajax is not setting the headers - React with TS

Tags: ajax, reactjs, typescript

I am using React With Redux and I wrote a middleware that comes in handy when I do Ajax calls in Epics. For example, to do a `GET` request, I have this `getJSON` function.

```
import {ajax, AjaxResponse} from "rxjs/ajax";

const getJSON = (url: string, headers?: Object): Observable<AjaxResponse> =>
    ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url,
        responseType: "json",
        headers,
        withCredentials: true
    });
```

Everything seem to work fine except that `Ajax` does not set the headers that contains the access token.

When I step through the code, the `headers` object looks like this,

```
{
    Authorization: "Bearer ey-SOME-ACCESS-TOKEN"
}
```

As expected... But when I look through the network calls, it does not contain the specified header with its value.

Parsed:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:1337
Origin: http://localhost:3000
```

Source:

```
OPTIONS /api/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1337
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

NOTE: Please don't mark this as duplicate. I know there are similar questions on SO, but none of them seem to work for me.

---

After 3 days of pulling my hairs and banging my head on the walls, I finally figure out what is the problem, but still not sure why/how. Apparently due to `CORS`, there is always `OPTION` request is made before the actual `POST` or `GET` request. Which I already knew and kinda make sense. What does not make sense to me is why the heck it does not contain the headers. If anyone can explain this to me will be eligible for the bounty on this question.

I had to made changes in my back-end to handle `OPTION` requests, and it seems to work for now. I can't spend more time of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's late enough, but might be useful for future readers.

You should configure your server not to expect for `authorization` header in OPTIONS request.

The `Bearer` token is used for the `POST`/`GET`/`DELETE`/`...` confirmation of identity. The OPTIONS is just a `preflight` to see if the current `HOST` is allowed to get the data back.

It's important to say that browsers most of the time remove the custom headers from the OPTIONS request, moving them into the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` (it's happening in your case).

Please, take a look on the official documentation here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I end up doing.

Comment: This is a browser specificity. There isn't much what you can do about it.